# Nuxt.js Page Component Html from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can i load and render Page Components template from API or string variable? For example`pageContent = "<Header/><Slider/><NewArrivals/><Footer/>"` . I want to render this string. Are there any methods available?

I tried this;

```
    <script>
    import List from '~/components/account/role/List.vue'
    export default {
      components: {
        List
      },
      template: this.pageContent,
      data: () => {
        return {
          pageContent: '<div class="row"><List class="col-lg-12"/></div>',
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

So i getting error;

```
render function or template not defined in component: anonymous
```

Comment: could you provide some tried code

Comment: I tried v-html but components are not rendering.

Comment: did you try `Vue.component('comp-name',{template:pageContent,...})` ?

Comment: I tried now but getting error. I edit my question now.

Comment: could you show how to get pageContent from API?

Comment: I am not get from API now. If i render this string, i will try to get content from api.